# How to set columns via AJAX in Tabulator 4.1

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to create a tabulator 4.1 table with columns that will load via AJAX. Preferably without jQuery, although it could be used if it makes a large difference. I have tried the following to no avail:

```
table.setColumns("ajaxr.php?act=GetTabuColumns&vals=data");
```

and

```
$("#display").tabulator("setColumns", "ajax.php?act=GetTabuColumns&vals=data");
```

I've also tried doing separate ajax request with plain Javascript as well as a jQuery ajax request. The date would load as a json encoded array, but it would throw the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.forEach is not a function
at t.setColumns (tabulator.min.js:2)
at t.c.setColumns (tabulator.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange ((index):71)
```

I'm fairly new to javascript so it could me I'm making a basic mistake. How should this be done?

My basic setup is as follows:

```
function datatablemaker(table){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var newcolumns = this.responseText;

                var table = new Tabulator("#display", {
            columns:[
            {title:'ID', field:'ID', sorter:'number'},...
            {title:'Create Time', field:'Create Time', sorter:'string'}
            ],
    });
table.setData("ajax.php?act=GetTabuData&vals=data");
table.setColumns(newcolumns);

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET",'ajax.php?act=GetTabuColumns&vals=data',true);
        xmlhttp.send();


};
document.getElementById("View").addEventListener("click", datatablemaker);
```

**EDIT:**

I got it to work if I used JSON.parse, but I know that there should be a better way to do this. i.e.

```
var newcolumns = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in way to do this at the moment, that will be coming in the 4.2 release later in the month.

in the mean time making an ajax request and passing the column array into the ***setColumns*** function is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks! I did that for now. Amazing library! Thank you!